# Silverlight and memory usage

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My silverlight application is taking up 75 megs of memory.  This seems high.  How can I troubleshoot the application to see where the memory is being used.  Is there any trick like running a low memory mode that would reduce my footprint for S light!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matt Bridges suggestion for a profiler is correct. I have also used ANTS. Other alternatives include Yourkit and using WinDbg SOS.

There isn't one answer to your question so it might get closed, however, there are memory leaks with inline Data Templates in your controls. Here is an example, but there are lots of pages when you google for it: http://www.devtoolshed.com/silverlight-memory-leak-datagrid-dataform-datatemplate-etc

Answer (score 1):

One place to start is the [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/features/), which works with Silverlight.